# drupal: disable input validation when using drupal_bootstrap()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a created a drupal 7 module that pulls data from custom tables in the database.

The database is fed from a separate admin area, that uses drupal's database and session api, with

```
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION)
```

The problem is that, when I submit a form, and a field has a url, it returns a 403 forbidden error and the record is not updated/created.

I have checked error logs, and nothing appears, I guess its because of drupal's core input validation.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It's not likely to be a validation issue, no validation functions in Drupal core invoke a 403 header that I know of.

It's far more likely that you're not logged in and so don't have access to the page you're trying to submit to. You can 'fake' a login like so immediately after your call to `drupal_bootstrap`:

```
$form_state['uid'] = 1;
user_login_submit(array(), $form_state);
```

That should fix the problem. If you don't want the script to run with full permissions then you probably want to use a user ID other than 1 (the super user).

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, I am logged in.

Actually, I use the login info to give access to the page, if there isn't a session, it will die.

Also, I'm not using drupal's forms api. I'm using plain html forms.

Comment: Does the file you're posting the form to physically exist on the server?

Comment: Of course, everything works if I don't enter any kind of url or html in the text areas or inputs.

That's why I think it is drupal's validation.